# problem in IIS - 404 error in server site

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, iis, web-config, wwwroot

I wrote a project in .NET CORE 5 + react

(visual studio + vs code)

And I uploaded this project to IIS (server side and client side).

The client is running

But the server side falls to me

and I get 404.0 error

The development environment works normally

(in the localhost)

this is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
            <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
       <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
<httpHandlers>
        <add type="ReportRESTWebService.Service, ReportRESTWebService" verb="*" path="report" 
/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" culture="neutral" 
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" 
 newVersion="5.1.0.0"/>
                 </dependentAssembly>
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" culture="neutral" 
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" 
newVersion="5.1.0.0"/>
                </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" 
type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, 
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 
/nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" 
type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, 
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 
/nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
     </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
      <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>

   <security>
   <requestFiltering>
     <verbs applyToWebDAV="true">
          <remove verb="PUT" />
          <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
          <remove verb="DELETE" />
          <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
          <remove verb="PATCH" />
          <add verb="PATCH" allowed="true" />
      </verbs>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" 
preCondition="" />
            </modules>
            <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
resourceType="Unspecified" />
            <add name="report" path="report" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" 
scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.5.2\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" 
preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.5.2,bitness64" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <add name="StaticFile1" path="*" verb="*" 
modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" 
requireAccess="Read" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" 
type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" 
requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
                  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myProject_server.dll" 
stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Staging" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
                          <defaultDocument enabled="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

Is there something missing here?

Or should something else be added to the project?

like wwwroot folder?

Comment: `<system.web>` <-- Why do you have this in your config file?

Comment: I think `<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
resourceType="Unspecified" />` should have `modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2"` instead.

Comment: I need remove this tag?
 <system.web>

Comment: Not necessary, I was asking why you had it there in the first place. ASP.NET Core doesn't use `web.config` files (execpt for configuring IIS's `AspNetCoreModuleV2`).

Comment: it's not work for me...

Comment: You mixed too much in `web.config` so why not take a few steps back? If you use `dotnet publish` to generate the artifacts for your web project, what's the content of `web.config` in the publish folder?

Comment: You need to use failed request tracing to see details about 404 errors.